# Widget and Textinput doesn't appear on Kivy Screen

Tags: widget, kivy, textinput

Everything seems to be perfect but on Kivy screen, nothing appears, just black screen! I've tried to rearrange the positions of imports and even installed the pygame but still the problem keeps persisting!

```
import kivy
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.app import App




class MyGrid(GridLayout):
    def __init___(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyGrid, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 2
        self.add_widget(Label(text="Name: "))
        self.name = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.add_widget(self.name)


        self.add_widget(Label(text="Last Name: "))
        self.lastname = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.add_widget(self.lastname)


        self.add_widget(Label(text="Email: "))
        self.email = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.add_widget(self.email)




class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an extra underscore on line `def __init___(self, **kwargs):` after `init` word. Please remove that and then it should run ok.